# MvvmCross: MvxAdapter GetBindableView method loops indefinitely on first child

Tags: android, mvvmcross, android-adapter, android-fragmentactivity, android-gridview

The `GetBindableView` method of my adapter is called normally for all childs of my MvxGridView, but then it loops indefinitely on the first child.

In a MvxFragment I set an adapter to a MvxGridView in the `OnCreateView` method:

```
public class MetronomeFragment : MvxFragment<MetronomeViewModel>, View.IOnTouchListener
{
    public override View OnCreateView (LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        var ignored = base.OnCreateView (inflater, container, savedInstanceState);
        var view = this.BindingInflate (Resource.Layout.fragment_metronome, null);

        // GridView
        var gridView = view.FindViewById<MvxGridView>(Resource.Id.grid_view);
        gridView.Adapter = new CustomAdapter (Activity, (MvxAndroidBindingContext)BindingContext);

        return view;
    }
}
```

A part of my view:

```
<Mvx.MvxGridView
    android:id="@+id/grid_view"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_centerInParent="true"
    android:stretchMode="columnWidth"
    android:numColumns="5"
    android:verticalSpacing="@dimen/metronome_grid_view_vertical_spacing"
    local:MvxBind="ItemsSource MeasureViewModel.Measure.BeatList"
    local:MvxItemTemplate="@layout/template_item_metronome_beat" />
```

My template:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v7.widget.CardView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:local="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="@dimen/item_metronome_beat_layout_width"
    android:layout_height="@dimen/item_metronome_beat_layout_height"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    local:cardBackgroundColor="@color/card_view"
    local:cardCornerRadius="@dimen/card_view_corner_radius"
    local:MvxBind="CardElevation BoolToElevation(IsPlaying, 2); Alpha BoolToAlpha(IsPlaying, 0.5)">
    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_margin="@dimen/item_metronome_beat_margin">
        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:scaleType="fitXY"
            local:MvxBind="DrawableId BeatToImageResource(.)" />
        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:textSize="@dimen/text_small"
            local:MvxBind="Text Number" />
    </RelativeLayout>
</android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
```

Here is my custom adapter:

```
public class CustomAdapter : MvxAdapter
{
    public CustomAdapter(Context context, IMvxAndroidBindingContext bindingContext)
            : base(context, bindingContext)
    {
    }

    protected override View GetBindableView(View convertView, object source, int templateId)
    {
        var beat = (Beat)source;
        Mvx.Trace (beat.Number.ToString ());

        return base.GetBindableView(convertView, source, templateId);
    }
}
```

For this test purpose, I just log the beat number (DataContext object). The list contains 4 beats and the output is: 1, 2, 3, 4, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, ... And it loops always on first child!!!

I'm using MvvmCross 4.0.0-beta5.

Anyone has an idea?

Cheers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I finally found an explanation!
It's an unexpected screen refresh due to a combination of a `ViewTreeObserver.GlobalLayout` event and a `RelativeLayout`.

I have this code in my main activity `OnCreate` method to be able to display (as a temporary onscreen debug info) the screen size and density:

```
var contentView = FindViewById<View> (Window.IdAndroidContent);
var sizeText = FindViewById<Android.Widget.TextView> (Resource.Id.size_text);
contentView.ViewTreeObserver.GlobalLayout += (sender, e) => {
    var height = (int) ((contentView.Height)/Resources.DisplayMetrics.Density);
    var width = (int) ((contentView.Width)/Resources.DisplayMetrics.Density);
    sizeText.Text = height + " x " + width + " " + Resources.DisplayMetrics.DensityDpi.ToString();
};
```

What I didn't know, is that this method is called repetitively. It implies that the text in the `TextView` is changed several times per seconds (even if the size hasn't changed).

My main view is:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:local="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@drawable/background">
    <include
        android:id="@+id/toolbar"
        layout="@layout/toolbar" />
    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/size_text" />
    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/content_frame"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_below="@id/toolbar"
        android:layout_above="@+id/ad_view" />
    <com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView
        android:id="@id/ad_view"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        local:adSize="BANNER"
        local:adUnitId="@string/ad_unit_id" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

My `FrameLayout` containing my `GridView` is contained in a RelativeLayout as well as my `TextView`. As the content of the `TextView` always changes, the size of every views is recalculated. And it's also the case for the `GridView`, which implied a call to the `GetBindable` method.

To avoid this call loop when getting the size, make your activity to implement `Android.Views.ViewTreeObserver.IOnGlobalLayoutListener` and add this in the `OnCreate` method:

```
var contentView = FindViewById<View> (Window.IdAndroidContent);
contentView.ViewTreeObserver.AddOnGlobalLayoutListener(this);
```

And add this method:

```
public void OnGlobalLayout ()
{
    var metrics = Resources.DisplayMetrics;
    var contentView = FindViewById<View> (Window.IdAndroidContent);
    var sizeText = FindViewById<Android.Widget.TextView> (Resource.Id.size_text);
    var height = (int) ((contentView.Height)/metrics.Density);
    var width = (int) ((contentView.Width)/metrics.Density);
    sizeText.Text = height + " x " + width + " " + metrics.DensityDpi.ToString();
    contentView.ViewTreeObserver.RemoveOnGlobalLayoutListener(this);
}
```

Have a nice weekend folks!!!!